# Finding the interval of which a multivariable function is defined

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find the interval in which $f(x,y,z)=z+ln(1-x^2-y^2)$ is defined

So all that is need to to check for which values $ln(1-x^2-y^2)\geq0$

That mean $1-x^2-y^2\geq 1 \rightarrow x^2+y^2\geq 0$

But how do I find the specific $x$ terms and $y$ terms?

Or is $x^2+y^2\geq 0$ is sufficient?

Comment: It is sufficient, but do you recognize $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: @Paul yem, it is a circle

Comment: there is a mistake: if you want to check $ln(1-x^2-y^2)\geq 0$ then you must find the $x$'s and $y$'s satisfying $1-x^2-y^2\geq 1$ and not $1-x^2-y^2\geq 0$ as you wrote.

Comment: @CarloVonSchnitzel right, edited

Comment: Okay sorry what I've said is crazy. I'm sorry I didn't read the whole post above, just spotted the mistake, but to check the domain of $f$ you must check where $ln(1-x^2-y^2)$ is defined. This function is defined exactly when $1-x^2-y^2>0$, i.e exactly when $x^2+y^2<1$ by basic algebra. This means that the only points $(x,y)$ in the plane satisfying this equation are inside a circle of radius $1$.

Comment: So the domain of $f$ must be the set of all points $(x,y)$ in the plane which are inside the circle of radius 1 centered at $(0,0)$. Everything else is excluded, including the boundary of that circle of radius 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only partly right: if the only thing that you want is for $f$ to be defined, then $\ln$ must be defined, which means that its argument must be $>0$. In formulae: $1 - x^2 - y^2 > 0$, which means $x^2 + y^2 <1$, which is the interior of the circle of radius $1$ and center $(0,0)$. There is absolutely no reason why the logarithm should be positive, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

it is sufficient, you don't need separate limits on $x$ and $y$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/586623)

Comment: Sorry! I myself wanted to comment but could not due to insuffciient points.